# Ionic unable to showing modal

Tags: ionic-framework, modal-dialog

I'm currently facing a problem for showing a modal on ionic (1.7.14). I've created simple app with one page containing a list and an add button. On this button, i would like to show a modal for adding new elements in my tasks's list.

Here's my sample code

modal.html (new file created in www/templates folder)

```
<ion-modal-view>
    <!-- Modal header bar -->
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-secondary">
      <h1 class="title">New Task</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <!-- Modal content area -->
    <ion-content>
        <button class="button" ng-click="closeModal()">back</button>
      <form ng-submit="AddItem(data)">
        <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="What do you need to do?" ng-model="data.newItem">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="padding">
          <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive">Add item</button>
        </div>
      </form>

    </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

controller.js file

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('ToDoListCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicModal) {

// array list which will contain the items added
$scope.toDoListItems = [{
task: 'First task',
status: 'not done'
}, {
task: 'Second task',
status: 'not done'
}];

//init the modal
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
}).then(function (modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
});

// function to open the modal
$scope.openModal = function () {
    $scope.modal.show();
};

// function to close the modal
$scope.closeModal = function () {
    $scope.modal.hide();
};

//Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    $scope.modal.remove();
});

//function to add items to the existing list
$scope.AddItem = function (data) {
    $scope.toDoListItems.push({
        task: data.newItem,
        status: 'not done'
    });
    data.newItem = '';
    $scope.closeModal();
};

});
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller.js"></script>

</head>
<!--<body ng-app="starter">-->
<body ng-app="starter">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Todo list</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button icon ion-plus" ng-click="openModal()">   </button>
    </div>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
      <ion-list ng-controller="ToDoListCtrl">
        <ion-item ng-repeat="item in toDoListItems">
          {{item.task}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
 </body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])
.run(function ($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
if (window.StatusBar) {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
});
})
```

I tried to add console.log('test') before opening modal and, log command is not diplayed in the console...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you attach your controller to the view in the `<ion-list>` and the button is created before, so it doesn't work. You have to add `ng-controller="ToDoListCtrl"` before the button is created.

Comment: You mean in the body tag ?

Answer (score 0):

you have include the controller to the list item but you are trying to call the function in the controller outside the list.
so try with this.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller.js"></script>

</head>
<!--<body ng-app="starter">-->
<body ng-app="starter">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Todo list</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button icon ion-plus" ng-click="openModal()">   </button>
    </div>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content ng-controller="ToDoListCtrl">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="item in toDoListItems">
          {{item.task}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
 </body>
</html>
```